# Windows boot menu не дает продолжить загрузку ОС

Tags: windows, boot

Пытаюсь я установить Винду на новый Lenovo IdeaPad 3. С завода при включении на нем BootMenu. Все позиции и любые кнопки приводят к перезагрузке страницы и попаданию в это же меню, только при нажатии таб можно выбрать пункт и открыть BIOS.

Проблема не редкая, и в СНГ комюнити и в инглиш спикин. Собственно весь день ковырял настройки биоса и интернеты, в поиске решения. В 90% случаев для решения этой проблемы рекомендуют поменять Boot mode с UEFI на Legacy. Но вот в проблема, В МОЕМ БИОСЕ НЕТУ ЭТОЙ НАСТРОЙКИ.

Прилагаю фото всех страничек биоса, все видимые конфигурации я скорее всего клацал. Но жду ваших предложений.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так понял, что Вы Винду хотите поставить с флешки, а интерфейс у флешки USB 3.0. Верно?

Comment: Ну а винду чем на флэшку писал?